# Find "part" duplicated content

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find "part" duplicated content?
I have links that weren't updated properly and i left with two similar links instead of one, where only the sub-domain is different.

for example:

```
link1: domain-1.com/file_path
links2 domain-2.com/file_path
```

I would like to find all links where "file_path" is duplicated in `file` column.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT file, COUNT( * ) c
FROM my_table
GROUP BY file HAVING c >1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '.com', -1)) as "c", 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '.com', -1) as "f" 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY f HAVING c > 1
```

Where `f` is the duplicated file name and `c` is the number of occurences.

To obtain a list of all links you could try:

```
    SELECT m.file from mytable as "m" 
    WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.file, '.com', -1) IN (
        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(m2.file, '.com', -1) as "f" 
        FROM mytable as "m2"
        GROUP BY f HAVING COUNT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m2.file, '.com', -1)) > 1
        )
```

Comment: seams to work, but `(m2.file, '/', -1)` removes everything until the last slash, so only the file-name remains. In my case `file_path` contains many folders for example: `http://domain-2.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file-name.jpg` I need to check for `dir1/dir2/dir3/file-name.jpg`

Comment: You can try changing the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions to take everything after the `.com` instead of `/`. Ex: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.file,'.com',-1)` to get the file path you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is almost correct, but you'd want to update your `HAVING` clause to actually reflect what you want.

I think the best approach would be to use a `REGEX`, but I think this will also do for simple queries: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

If you are sure that there is only one `/` then it would be easy. Namely:

```
SELECT myfile, COUNT(*) c
FROM my_table
GROUP BY myfile HAVING SUBSTRING_INDEX(myfile, '/', -1);
```

I haven't tested the query, so not 100% sure if it'll work and I've replaced `file` with `myfile` as `FILE` seems to be a reserved keyword, though I do not know if it actually matters.